# Measurable sets using closed aproximation

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Show the following. $E$ is measurable $\Longleftrightarrow$ For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a closed set $F \subset E$ such that $m^*(E) - m^*(F) < \epsilon$

I have proved $"\Rightarrow"$ direction. I am having difficulties on $"\Leftarrow"$.

Comment: This is about Lebesgue measure, right?

Comment: Correct $m^*$ is outer measure

Comment: Could you outline the proof of $\Rightarrow$? Is it for $m^*(E)<+\infty$? Would be nice to see your thoughts and what kind of difficulties you get on proving the converse too.

Comment: (a) $E$ is measurable and $m^*(E) <\infty$, there is a closed set $F_k$ that is included in $E$ and for which $m^*(E - F_k) <\epsilon$
 
 Define $F = F_k$

Since $E$ has finite measure and $F \subset E \Rightarrow F$ has finite measure, therefore we can use excision property and monotonicity $\Rightarrow$,
 $m^*(E) - m^*(F) = m^*(E - F) \leq m^*(E - F_k) \leq \epsilon$
 
  $ m^*(E) - m^*(F) \leq \epsilon$
  
  (b) Similar when  $E$ is measurable and $m^*(E)=\infty$